# Calculating field gives invalid expression in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I am a new user of QGIS and I want to add a new field in my attribute table named `densite` which can be calculated by POP(population) / Area, in Field Calculator, I wrote POP/Area no result !! invalid expression.

[image]

What should I do ?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. In this case, information about your attribute table fields is necessary. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2):

When you don't compose the expression by point and click be sure to surround field names with double quotation marks.

```
"POP"/"Area"
```

To include string constants use single quotation marks.